# how to group other group permissions in django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm creating e-commerce website using django and drf. My project has many apps like, products, sales, logistics, warehouses and etc... I'm also making new admin dashboard (not using django's built-in). Now I want to make fully dynamic role-based authentication in my admin page. I made group authentication for each apps. Now I want to make such a function that **SuperAdmin** can create roles (such as: Operator, Driver and etc...) and give them group permissions (like operator should have access on products and warehouses). How can I group two or three groups together? or are there any better methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better method would be to use group as role. Instead of trying to merge several groups into a new entity that you would call role, set the required permissions for each role. This is, presuming you use `django.contrib.auth`.

You can easily expose an interface for these tables to the front-end via whatever type of admin you use.